# Javascript error while using EncryptedLocalStore

Tags: javascript, air

I am trying to make my first JS-based adobe air app.

But I've stuck at a point.

Here's the code which is causing the error

```
  var RunUrl  =   'http://www.lilpirate.net';
  var firstRunUrl =   'http://www.netbloo.com';
  var snxApp   = air.EncryptedLocalStore.getItem( 'snxApp' );
  var semail   =   snxApp.readUTFBytes( snxApp.bytesAvailable );
  if( semail!='786') {
     data = new air.ByteArray();
     data.writeUTFBytes( '786' );
     air.EncryptedLocalStore.setItem( 'snxApp', data ); 
     var snxUrlToLoad    =   firstRunUrl;
  }
  else
     var snxUrlToLoad    =   RunUrl;
```

When compiling it from adl, it throws error -

> TypeError: Result of expression 'snxApp' [null] is not an object.

Help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are accessing properties (`bytesAvailable` and `readUTFBytes`) of `snxApp` without checking to make sure it exists first. If you haven't used `setItem` to store anything with that name yet, it will be `null`.

Here's an example of how it would look with an `if` statement:

```
var snxApp = ...;
var semail;
if (snxApp !== null) {
    semail = snxApp.readUTFBytes( snxApp.bytesAvailable );
}
...
```

Comment: Yep. I worked it around by using try and catch functions. It works great now :-) Thanks!

Comment: @KPL: try/catch works, but the code might be more clear if you add an `if (snxApp !== null)` check before you set `semail`.